# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socke in CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I have a dedicated server with CentOS 7 command line OS, and then I remove MariaDB from it and download MySQL RPM packages(`Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 / Oracle Linux 7 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Bundle 5.7.1 557.1M`) and then run rpm -ivh --replacefiles mysql-*.rpm for install that.

after install when I try to check `mysql -version` I face with this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

when I check the mysql datadir path in `/var/lib/mysql/`, this path haven't any files !!

please help me how I can install and then run MySQL server from rpm packages(offline mode) and then use it in CentOS 7. and How I can fix this problem.

thanks for helps.

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl status mysqld` and check if server is running and then check if it is set to use sockets in server configuration file.

Comment: mysqld.service - MySQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Friday 2016-12-30 04:42:16 EST; 36s ago
  Process: 24760 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 24760 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

December 30 04:42:16 vps.dnswebhost.com mysqld_safe[24760]: Executing: /u...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Comment: It seems like it failed to start `Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Friday 2016-12-30 04:42:16 EST...` Try displaying logs for myslq service: `sudo journalctl -u mysqld.service`. There should be some hints what failed at start.